# base-input can't pass data to back-end in vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I'm curious why I can't pass input data using "base-input",
But when I using "input" I can pass my data.
This is my front-end code:

```
      <form @submit.prevent="pressed">
        <base-input placeholder="email" addon-left-icon="ni ni-email-83" type="email" v-model="email"/>

        <base-input formClasses="input-group-alternative mb-3" placeholder="Password" type="password" addon-left-icon="ni ni-lock-circle-open" v-model="password"/>

        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

This is my back-end script:

```
methods: {
    pressed() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          this.$router.replace({ name: "home" });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.message;
          alert(err.message)
          console.log(err.message)
          console.log(this.email, this.password)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by not passing data to backend ?

Comment: I want use value email and password and insert it as a value for firebase auth, but when I try it, It always show an error and I try to show it in console, it shows nothing. But when I use "input" instead of "base-input" it worked. I'm just curious why

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you are not sending your data to database SQL, try connect your firebase jquery to SQL/Dolphin

if you try just using JS/firebase:
passing/allow bypass auth would be:

```
$("#pass-submit").click(function () {
  if (pass.val() == "password") {
    lock1.fadeOut("fast", function () {
      lock2.fadeIn("slow");
    });
  } else {
    lock1.fadeOut("fast", function () {
      wrongPg.fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }
});
$(pass).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("#pass-submit").click();
  }
});
```

Sample Link of using Passing JS:
[Click Here](https://alexandereric995.github.io/forensicsample/)